# "Unchecking" tracks playing music on iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, music.app

My audio intake from iPhone outweighs that of my Macbook by a double-digit ratio.

Sometimes I encounter an audio track on-the-go that I would like to delete, remove from the playlist, or at least remove the track from the rotation. In iTunes, I would delete the file from the library or uncheck the box next to the track's name.

How can I remove a track from rotation on my iPhone?

iOS 7.1.2, iPhone 5s. *jb solutions welcome*

Answer (score 1):

In the Songs list or Playlist, just swipe it to the left, like you would an unwanted email, text etc

I haven't tested whether this 'reports back' to iTunes & unchecks it there - I'm running a sync now to see & will edit...

***Edit:***  it doesn't delete or uncheck the track from 'My Music', the definitive iTunes list; but it does remove it from an iTunes Playlist after sync.